# How to copy files with MSBuild to the same folder but with different extensions?

Tags: msbuild, copy, msbuild-task

Let's say I have an ItemGroup defined as follows:

```
  <ItemGroup>
<ReactorFile Include="MyExecutable\bin\x86\Release\MyExecutable.exe"/>
<ReactorFile Include="MyLibrary\bin\x86\Release\MyLibrary*.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Defined a PropertyGroup:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<ReactorUnObfuscatedFileExt>.unobfuscated</ReactorUnObfuscatedFileExt>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I also have defined a Target in another file:

```
<Target Name="CopyUnprotectedFiles">
  <!-- Copy unobfuscated file to  "unobfuscated file".unobfuscated -->
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(ReactorFile)"
    DestinationFiles="@(ReactorFile -> '%(Filename)%(Extension)$(ReactorUnObfuscatedFileExt)"
    SkipUnchangedFiles="false"
/>
</Target>
```

Unfortunately due to my lack of experience in MSBuild I did it wrong.
Could somebody please correct it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out:

Adding a *%(RelativeDir)* Item Metadata was the solution.

Maybe other will use it as an example.
Corrected fragment is:

```
<Target Name="CopyUnprotectedFiles">
  <!-- Copy unobfuscated file to  "unobfuscated file".unobfuscated -->
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(ReactorFile)"
    DestinationFiles="@(ReactorFile -> '%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)$(ReactorUnObfuscatedFileExt)')"
    SkipUnchangedFiles="false"
/>
</Target>
```